# Unable to Pause Activity - Illegal State Exception while playing bgm in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, illegalstateexception

(I've already solved it, just scroll down until EDIT 2)

I have an application that, upon opening, plays a background music on loop. I decided I could take it a notch further and pause the bgm when the app is paused and played where it paused on resume. It works fine.

However, the problem I encounter is when I exit the application. It gives the error: 
`10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.cs119.megamanstrikes/com.cs119.megamanstrikes.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException`

My onCreate looks like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    backgroundMusic = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.mmbn_3);
    backgroundMusic.setLooping(true);
    backgroundMusic.start();

    Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Start);
    Button highScore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.highScore);
    Button quit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quit);

    start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            startGame();
        }
    });

    highScore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            highScore();
        }
    });

    quit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            quit();
        }
    });


}
```

These are the overrides for onPause and onResume:

```
@Override 
public void onPause(){
   super.onPause();
   backgroundMusic.pause();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    backgroundMusic.start();
}
```

And when the user clicks on the quit button or the back button:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    quit();
}

public void quit(){
    quitDialog();
}

private void quitDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    // Set title.
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("QUIT");

    // Set dialog message.
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to quit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //backgroundMusic.stop();
                            backgroundMusic.release();
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, resume teh gaem
                    //inputName();
                }
            });

    // Create alert dialog.
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // Show it.
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

After clicking "Yes" to quit the game, the app freezes and force closes. Here's the full LogCat error

```
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.cs119.megamanstrikescom.cs119.megamanstrikes.MainActivity}:java.lang.IllegalStateException
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:946)
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): at android.media.MediaPlayer._pause(Native Method)
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): at android.media.MediaPlayer.pause(MediaPlayer.java:1001)
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): at com.cs119.megamanstrikes.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:163)
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:3877)
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1191)
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
10-07 22:50:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(5852): ... 12 more
```

I've also tried to do `backgroundMusic.stop();` instead of `backgroundMusic.pause()` in the onPause method, however, upon resuming the application, the sound doesn't play even if `backgroundMusic.play()` is present in the onResume() Method.

I've also noticed that the error is still there regardless of what I place in the onPause() and onResume() and I try to Quit the application.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT 1:
I place system.out lines in the onPause and onResume overrides so that I can see when it is executed. Upon starting the application, onResume executes and upon closing the application, onPause executes. I am very confused on why this is happening since onResume is different from onCreate.

EDIT 2:
Okay I've solved the problem. The problem mainly comes from the quit button, as it executes these lines of code:

```
backgroundMusic.stop();
backgroundMusic.release();
finish();
```

It somehow goes to the onPause method and tries to execute `backgroundMusic.pause()`. Now the app Force Closes because the backgroundMusic has already been released and it couldn't finish the command `backgroundMusic.pause()`.

I got around this problem by creating another global variable:
    boolean flag = false;

This flag checks if the quit button has been selected and if the user wants to quit the game. Once the user wants to quit the game, it will set the flag to true.

```
flag = true;
backgroundMusic.stop();
backgroundMusic.release();
finish();
```

I set the flag to true so that when it goes to the onPause() method from finish() (I may be wrong with regards to the activity life cycle of Android but it seems that onPause() is executed within or after finish()), this will execute:

```
@Override 
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(!flag){
        if(backgroundMusic.isPlaying()){
            backgroundMusic.pause();
        }
    }

}
```

Here, it will only execute super.onPause() if the user wants to Quit the game. Otherwise, if the game was really paused (via the home button or something), then the Flag would still be false and the background music will be paused.

I also modified onResume() to be safe:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(!backgroundMusic.isPlaying()){
        backgroundMusic.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would check before pause and on resume if(backgroundMusic!=null) and maybe also backgrounmusic.isplaying...
Just guessing but try to change order in onpause method. First pause and then super.onPause.

Comment: Me too got this crash on onPause. And add flag how you, and will hope crash is gone =) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the Android docs:

"IllegalStateException if the internal player engine has not been initialized or has been released."

I would say first make sure that you have initialized and/or have not released the player.

you need to release the player in onPause() also unless you have a very special requirement to keep it around.

Also,  if you are using a static global variable for your MediaPLayer, that could be the problem. Double check how it's being initialized and released, especially when switching between classes and stuff like that.

If you really need to save the state then you can save the current position of the track using `getCurrentPosition()` method in your onPause() and in your onResume() you can use  `seekTo (int msec)` method and pass in the value you obtained from getCUrrentPosition() so that you can resume playback where you left off.

official docs for these functions are [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getCurrentPosition%28%29) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo%28int%29)

Comment: I need to keep the backgroundMusic in onPause() so I can play it on where it left off on onResume() method. I think I've solved the problem which involved my onPause() method.